# How to query two collections?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two schemas,

info has 
    user,
    followers: [],
    following[],
    profile_photo,
    biography

and post has
    user,
    username,
    photo,
    descriptio,
    post_created

user in post are equal to user in info

How do I query all post information + info profile_photo?

**EDIT 1:**

[INFO SCHEMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mdKD.png)

[USER SCHEMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWMgf.png)

Comment: does the second collection have information related to the first collection?

Comment: @SASSY_ROG no they only have user, which is the id from user collection

Comment: post the schema for both collections

Comment: @SASSY_ROG done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
info.aggregate([
{
 $lookup: {
    from: "post",
    localField: "user",
    foreignField: "user",
    as: "posts"
   }
}
])
```

now all that users posts are are in array called "posts" on your document and you can continue querying as you'd like.